# How to display the most recent single record in laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How can i display the most recent single record in laravel using eloquent the solution i have shown below only shows the oldest record in the database not the most recent.

I have two tables a payments table and tenants table.
payments table has the following columns

- id
- amount
- rent_from
- rent_to

Payments table has a many to one relationship with the tenants table.

In my index page i wish to only display the latest payment per tenant (tenant_id)

In my controller i have

```
public function index() {
  $payments = Payment::groupBy('tenant_id')->get();
  return view('payments.index')->with('payments',$payments);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($payments as $post)
  {{ $post->id }}
  {{ $post->amount }}
  {{ $post->rent_from }}
  {{ $post->rent_to }}
  {{ $post->tenant['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

This show the oldest record not the latest. How can i display the most recent payment record for each tenant - only one most recent payment record per tenant_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a new relation called 'lastPayment' by using 'hasOne' with orderByDesc to get the last payment ....

```
class Tenant extends Model
{
public function lastPayment()
{
 return $this->hasOne(Payment::class,'tenant_id')->orderByDesc('payments.id');
}
}

 public function index()
    {
 $tenants= Tenant ::with('lastPayment')->get();
return view('payments.index')->with('tenants',$tenants);
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`latest()` is a function that will order by with the column you provide in descending order.

```
 public function index()
         {
               $payments = Payment::groupBy('tenant_id')->get()->latest('id');
               return view('payments.index')->with('payments',$payments);
         }
```

Comment: This gives an error. "Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: Wrap it in quotes ```latest('id')``` or If you have a timestamp column at the end of your table you can leave it at ```latest()``` instead of ```latest(id)``` and it will order by that column by default.

Comment: this still gives an error "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.
" what could be the reason

Comment: Remove ```->get()``` and it should work.
$payments = Payment::groupBy('tenant_id')->latest('id');

Answer (score 0):

The following gives me the output i needed. Is there a more eloquent way of expressing this function.

```
    {
$payments = Payment::whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM payments GROUP BY tenant_id)')->get();
return view('payments.index')->with('payments',$payments);}
```